# Studying the properties of geometrically arranged numbers

Tags: general-topology, algebraic-topology

I just started to read upon some topology so I'm still a newbie ;), so I need some help understanding how to arrange numbers in a geometric form and study the properties of some combination of numbers algebraically, e.g. squares of numbers.

For example: Given the numbers $ \mathbb{N}_9 $ (Natural Numbers Mod 9) where 9 Mod 9 = 9 instead of 0. I arrange them geometrically like in the following picture:
[image]

EDIT: The number map is created by the following rule (see picture):

[image]

In row 10 write down the numbers 1 2 4 8 7 5 1 and repeat to infinity (not shown in picture :P). Directly below in row 11 write the same numbers reversed (1 5 7 8 4 2 1). Then just "fill out" the rest of the number map by counting from 1-9 and 9-1 respectively in a 45 degree angle upwards and downwards and repeat.

For example: cell F11 is a 1 and cell G10 is 2. So cell H9 will be a 3, I8 will be a 4 and so on to 9 and repeat. In the same manner but counting downwards cell E12 will be a 9, D13 will be 8 and so on down to 1 and repeat.

Now I want to study the properties e.g. of the sums of numbers in all squares of different sizes (4,9,16 numbers in a square and so on). I colored a 4-square and a 9-square in the picture. For example I want to prove that the sum of any possible square (squares can overlap) of 4 numbers equals 9. In this picture 7+5+4+2=18/Mod 9= 9 (since 9 Mod 9 = 9).

Likewise I want to show that the sum of the numbers in every 9-square equals the numbers in the middle of the square e.g. 4+8+7+7+8+4+9+3+3=53/Mod 9=8.

Anyone has an idea how to tackle this problem? I don't require a solution to this, but some help how to start or what topics I could read up on in order to understand how to do this is appreciated :).

Comment: It seems like the diagonals alternate between increasing and decreasing sequences of numbers mod 9, and that it starts with the row $\dots1\;2\;4\;8\;7\;5\;1\;2\;4\;8\;7\;5\;\dots$. You should have included this information into your post if you were aware of this fact.

Comment: By the way: Where did you find this image?

Comment: Thanks for the hint Stefan, I added the rule for creating this special map although my question is also a more general one how to study any kind of geometrical arrangement of numbers algebraically. This map is the so called "rodin number map" based on the work of Marko Rodin's Vortex Based Mathematics from which he claims that this map is a 2-dimensional representation of a 3D-Torus and has interesting properties like that the sum of any size square equals the number in the centre and the sum of any 4-square is 9. But there exists no general proof of this claim only grafical ones.